# Question on domain and range of nonlinear, multivalued operator

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper by Crandall Liggett ("Generation of semi-groups...") and I have a question about one of the lemmas. 
I'll included some "background information" as I'm not sure if it's relevant for my question or not.

They say:

> A subset $B \subset X  \times X$ ($X$ is a Banach space) is called accretive if $(I+\lambda B)^{-1}$ is a function for $\lambda>0$ and:
>   $\lVert (I+\lambda B)^{-1}x- (I+\lambda B)^{-1}y \rVert \leq \lVert x-y \rVert$
>   for $x,y\in D((I+\lambda B)^{-1})$.

and further:

> a set $A \subset X \times X $ and a real number $\omega$ such that $A+\omega I$ is an accretive operator are fixed. If $\lambda$ is real let $J_\lambda$ denote the set$ (I+\lambda A)^{-1}$  and $D_\lambda=D(J_\lambda)$ be its domain.

**My question** is about the following step in the proof of Lemma 1.2.ii):

> Take $[x_1,y_1]\in A$ and $[x,y]\in A$ such that $x_1+\lambda y_1 =x$

For this to be possible one needs to have $x \in D(A)\cap R (I+\lambda A)$, but how does one know that this set is non-empty? Does it follow from one of the assumptions above or something more basic?

Comment: Is this your reference? `Crandall, Michael G., and Thomas M. Liggett. "Generation of semi-groups of nonlinear transformations on general Banach spaces." American Journal of Mathematics 93.2 (1971): 265-298.`

Comment: Yes, that’s it!

Comment: Please explain $B⊂X×X$ and $(I+λB)^{-1}$. Is $B$ really a set of ordered pairs? How do you scale, add an identity and invert these subsets of ordered pairs? Or is $B\subset X\otimes X^*$ a set of linear operators?

Comment: Self-answer for other uninitiates: $λB=\{(x,λy):(x,y)\in B\}$, $I+λB=\{(x,x+λy):(x,y)\in B\}$, $C^{-1}=\{(y,x): x,y\in C\}$, $x\in D((I+λB)^{-1})$ means thus that there is $(u,v)\in B$ so that $x=u+λv$, then $(I+λB)^{-1}x = \{u:(u,v)\in B\land x=u+λv\}$. Per assumption, this set only has one element in the considered case, so that the contractivity is equivalent to $\|u_x-u_y\|\le \|u_x+λv_x-u_y-λv_y\|$ which then looks similar to the definitions in the paper https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9379/ef559eb3628cceb964aac55c79b01d4f5da0.pdf

Comment: Yes, they sometimes write $B:X \to 2^X$ (the power  set of $X$). $B$ is allowed to take more then one value for each $x \in X$. Thanks for the link!